# How can you insert a templated number into an APIMocker response?

Tags: json, response, microservices

According to the API Mocker GitHub page [here](https://github.com/gstroup/apimocker), it says you can template your response using placeholders.

As an example, if you use this configuration entry...

```
"template/:Name/:Number" :{
    "mockFile": "templateSample.json",
    "verbs":["get"],
    "enableTemplate": true
    "contentType":"application/json"
}
```

Then you use this as your 'templateSample.json'...

```
{
    "Name": "@Name",
    "Number": "@Number"
}
```

If you call `/John/12345` it says you will be returned this...

```
{
    "Name": "John"
    "Number": 12345
}
```

But that's not what we're getting.  We're getting this (note the quotes around '12345')...

```
{
    "Name": "John"
    "Number": "12345"
}
```

The problem is our endpoints are expecting a pure number there, not a string.  Is there anything we can do to configure APIMocker to not wrap the values in quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.  The documentation is wrong.  In the template, you're not supposed to wrap the placeholder in quotes.  However, there's a huge caveat:

> If you use a placeholder whose value you don't want wrapped in quotes, ***the template file will no longer be valid JSON***, meaning you can't edit it in a JSON editor.  You have to edit it in a plain-text editor.

That's what stumped me. I thought the templates had to be valid JSON. They don't.  They **become** valid JSON after the substitutions are performed, but they don't have to be beforehand.

Anyway, hope this helps others!